# /var/www/html permssions issue, group not able to edit

Tags: linux, permissions, html, httpd, ownership

I'm having issues with permissions in /var/www/html and group permissions not working the way I thought they would.

```
bash-4.1$ whoami
barney

bash-4.1$ id barney
uid=507(barney) gid=511(barney) groups=511(barney),509(test-group)

bash-4.1$ ls -la /var/www
total 24
drwxrwxr-x+  6 frank test-group 4096 Apr 18 20:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  19 root  root       4096 Oct  7  2014 ..
drwxrwxr-x+  3 frank test-group 4096 Mar 22 15:04 cgi-bin
drwxrwxr-x+  3 frank test-group 4096 Apr 18 20:48 error
drwxrwxr-x+  2 frank test-group 4096 Apr 20 16:25 html
drwxrwxr-x+  3 frank test-group 4096 Apr 18 20:48 icons

bash-4.1$ ls -la /var/www/html
total 8
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 frank test-group 4096 Apr 20 16:25 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 6 frank test-group 4096 Apr 18 20:48 ..

bash-4.1$ touch test
touch: cannot touch `test': Permission denied

bash-4.1$ getenforce
Disabled
```

The user, Barney, is in the correct group, the group has permissions to /var/www/ and /var/www/html.

Barney can't create files in /var/www/html.

SELinux is disabled as well just making sure.

I'm probably just missing something but I'm losing my mind trying to figure it out at the moment so some outside advice would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like it was a facl issue, however that's odd it would be set by default? If anyone could shed some light on this it would be great!

`○●○/var/www -  getfacl html/
# file: html/
# owner: frank
# group: test-group
user::rwx
user:caswell:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:caswell:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x`

Comment: Is Barney in the right location? I.e. when he does `touch test`, is he in `/var/www/html`. Did you try `touch /var/www/html/test`?

Answer (score 1):

As can bee seen from the information you provided, members of group **test-group** hasn't right to create files and folders within **/html** folder. Set your ACL this way:

```
setfacl -Rm d:g:test-group:rwX,g:test-group:rwX /var/www/html
```

Or set explicit permissions for this folder:

```
chmod g+w /var/www/html
```

But permissions for newly created subfolders in this case remain **rwxr-xr-x** according to predefined umask for users in group **test-group**. So, you will have to chmod every subfolder again and again by hands. Therefore, the first way is preferable.